# Question about equivalent norms on $W^{2,2}(\Omega) \cap W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$.

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, functional-inequalities, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Assume $\mathbb{‎‎H}=W^{2,2}(\Omega) \cap W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$ with the norm induced from inner product
$$\langle u,v\rangle_{‎\mathbb{‎‎H}}=\int_\Omega \Delta u \,\Delta v\, dx$$
for any $u \in W^{2,2}(\Omega) \cap W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$ it is well-known that we have inequality (Rellich inequality)
$$ ‎\Lambda_N ‎\int_{\Omega}‎\frac{u^2}{|x|^4}\mathrm{d}x ‎\leq ‎\int_\Omega ‎|\Delta u|^2 \, ‎\mathrm{d}x‎
$$
 where $‎\Lambda_N=(‎\frac{N^2(N-4)^2}{16})‎$ is optimal constant and also it is known that
$$\|u\|^2=‎\int_\Omega ‎‎\Big(|\Delta u|^2-\Lambda_N \frac{u^2}{|x|^4}\Big) \, \mathrm{d}x $$ ‎
Defines an other norm on $W^{2,2}(\Omega) \cap W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$.

My question is this that is these two norm equivalent? To see an improved case of this inequality with reminder term see Corollary 1 of [Paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwiVtP_i0bLHAhWuFtsKHWvgBk0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Ftran%2F2004-356-06%2FS0002-9947-03-03395-6%2FS0002-9947-03-03395-6.pdf&ei=2iXTVZXfOK6t7AbrwJvoBA&usg=AFQjCNGqh1olY8Ot6v-SJEocxciuXDSs7g&sig2=onRbpOIea5shV-iIxQzjbg&bvm=bv.99804247,d.ZGU&cad=rjt).

I know if I could show that $W^{2,2}(\Omega) \cap W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$ is a hilbert space with the new inner product then this two norms must be equivalent due to Open mapping theorem.

Comment: Notice the difference between $||a||||b||$ and $\|a\|\|b\|$.  I set $\|u\|^2$ in the latter format, which is standard, where it had been in the former. ${}\qquad{}$